# How to display javascript tooltip when mouseover on scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollbar, mouseover

How do I make a javascript popup tooltip appear when the user mouses over the scrollbar of the browser window?

Comment: This is impossible as the toolbar is a OS governed element

Comment: You can't unless you create your own scrollbar, there are plugins for that.

Comment: Try using a Javascript of jQuery scrollbar

Comment: I think you can't, because the scrollbar is not part of the webpage. I think you'd have to fake it by creating your own scrollbar.  I'd enjoy seeing someone figure it out, though.

Comment: not a simple scenario...might consider adding a fixed position narrow element at window perimiter

Comment: Check scrollbars jquery plugins http://www.net-kit.com/jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/

Comment: Maybe look for the mouse pointer leaving the panel and then show a pop-up?  You won't know when to remove the pop-up, unless you have a panel on the other side of the scrollbar too.

Comment: It's possible! Is used on Google Docs. Read this:
http://googlesystem.blogspot.com.br/2014/08/google-docs-tooltip-shows-page-number.html

Answer (score 0):

The people in your comments are correct. You cannot do this with the browsers native scrollbar, you will have to use a custom one made of html css and js.

I HIGHLY recommend http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ I have had nothing but good luck with this scrollbar solutions. After you have jScrollPane installed you can do something as simple as `$('.jspVerticalBar').hover(function(){...` and even target style and control parts of the scrollbar. Like hovering over the track, or the drag.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation:

I believe the scroll bar is not actually a part of the webpage - it's an operating system level component. However, I was able to get around my issue by monitoring the mouse position over a parent element (with has an initial height and width value via css - that might be optional, I'm not certain. My code below was used in a slightly different context but I think it is applicable still).

The child elements width is re-sized upon needing the scrollbar(the width is decremented by 18 pixels, in Chrome). However, the parent element/container's width remains the same width. Because it stays the same width, we can add a mousemove event and check to see if the position of the cursor falls into that 18px gap where the scrollbar appears in the child element.

Also, depending on what exactly you mean by scrollbar (the entire bar; shaft, buttons, thumb and all) or components of the scrollbar you can achieve the functionality with the assistance of doing some calculations.

**Entire Scroll Bar - mouse over**

```
$(".parent").bind("mousemove",function(e){
    if($(".partent").width() <= e.offsetX){
        //display tool-tip div
    }else{
        //If displayed, hide tool-tip div
    }
});
```

**Scroll Bar Thumb - mouse over**

```
$(".parent").bind("mousemove",function(e){
    if($(".child").width() <= e.offsetX){
        var scrollbarHeight = $(".parent").height() - 36; //36 = height of both up and down arrows
        var scrollbarThumbHeight = scrollbarHeight/$(".child").height();
        var scrollTopPosition = $(".parent").get(0).scrollTop;
        var relativeThumbPosition = (childScrollTop/$(".child").height()) + 18;//18 = offset from the up button
        if(e.offsetY >= relativeThumbPosition && e.offsetY <= relativeThumbPosition+scrollbarThumbHeight){
            //display tooltip div
        }else{
            //If displayed, hide tool-tip div
        }
    }else{
        //If displayed, hide tool-tip div
    }
});
```

**Additional Mouse Out**

```
$(".parent").bind("mouseout",function(e){
    if($(".child").width() <= e.offsetX){
        //If displayed, hide tool-tip div
    }
});
```

I've only tested this in Google-Chrome on Windows 7, I think the magic numbers (36,18) would need to be tweeked for different Operating Systems but would be relatively similar in value.